# I am trying to understand the difference between the following queruies

Tags: sql, oracle, join, subquery, aggregate

I am having a salesperson and a customer table, and i am trying to find all salesman who live in any of the cities a customer lives in (note that the customer is associated to a specific salesman but for now we are just comparing the city)

CREATING TABLE (ORACLE)

```
CREATE TABLE SALESMAN (  
    SALESMAN_ID INT CONSTRAINT SALESMAN_PK PRIMARY KEY,  
    NAME VARCHAR2(15),  
    CITY VARCHAR2(10),  
    COMMISSION DECIMAL(4,2))
;

INSERT ALL  
    INTO SALESMAN VALUES(5001,'JAMES HOOG','NEW YORK',0.15)  
    INTO SALESMAN VALUES(5002,'NAIL KNITE','PARIS',0.13)  
    INTO SALESMAN VALUES(5005,'PIT ALEX','LONDON',0.11)  
    INTO SALESMAN VALUES(5006,'MC LYON','PARIS',0.14)  
    INTO SALESMAN VALUES(5003,'LAUSON HEN','SAN JOSE',0.12)  
    INTO SALESMAN VALUES(5007,'PAUL ADAM','ROME',0.13)  
SELECT * FROM DUAL
;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (   
    CUSTOMER_ID INT CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY,   
    CUST_NAME VARCHAR2(15),   
    CITY VARCHAR(10),   
    GRADE INT,   
    SALESMAN_ID INT,  
    CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTOMER_SALESMAN  
    FOREIGN KEY (SALESMAN_ID) REFERENCES SALESMAN (SALESMAN_ID)) 
;

INSERT ALL   
    INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (3002, 'NICK RIMANDO', 'NEW YORK', 100, 5001)   
    INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (3007, 'BRAD DAVIS', 'NEW YORK', 200, 5001)   
    INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (3005, 'GRAHAM ZUSI', 'CALIFORNIA', 200,5002)   
    INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (3008, 'JULIAN GREEN', 'LONDON', 300,5002)   
    INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (3004, 'FABIAN JOHSON', 'PARIS',300,5006)   
    INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (3009, 'GEOFF CAMEROON', 'BERLIN', 100,5003)   
    INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (3003, 'JOZY ALTIDOR', 'MOSCOW', 200,5007)   
    INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (3001, 'BRAD GUZAN', 'LONDON',NULL,5005)   
SELECT * FROM DUAL
;

SELECT * FROM SALESMAN;

SALESMAN_ID       NAME  CITY    COMMISSION
5001         JAMES HOOG NEW YORK    .15
5002         NAIL KNITE PARIS       .13
5005          PIT ALEX  LONDON      .11
5006          MC LYON   PARIS       .14
5003        LAUSON HEN  SAN JOSE    .12
5007          PAUL ADAM ROME        .13

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER;

CUSTOMER_ID       CUST_NAME      CITY      GRADE    SALESMAN_ID
3002            NICK RIMANDO    NEW YORK    100       5001
3007             BRAD DAVIS     NEW YORK    200       5001
3005             GRAHAM ZUSI    CALIFORNIA  200       5002
3008            JULIAN GREEN    LONDON      300       5002
3004           FABIAN JOHSON    PARIS       300       5006
3009           GEOFF CAMEROON   BERLIN      100       5003
3003            JOZY ALTIDOR    MOSCOW      200       5007
3001            BRAD GUZAN      LONDON       -        5005

# EXPECTED OUTPUT
SALESMAN_ID    NAME     CITY      COMMISSION
5001        JAMES HOOG  NEW YORK    .15
5006         MC LYON    PARIS       .14
5005        PIT ALEX    LONDON      .11
5002       NAIL KNITE    PARIS      .13

# QUERY 1

SELECT DISTINCT
SLS.*
FROM SALESMAN SLS, CUSTOMER CUST
WHERE SLS.CITY = CUST.CITY

# QUERY 2
SELECT * FROM SALESMAN SLS  
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT SALESMAN_ID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE SLS.CITY = CUSTOMER.CITY)

# QUERY 3
SELECT * FROM SALESMAN SLS  
WHERE SLS.SALESMAN_ID IN  (SELECT DISTINCT CUST.SALESMAN_ID FROM CUSTOMER CUST WHERE SLS.CITY = CUST.CITY)
;

# OUTPUT FROM QUERY 3
SALESMAN_ID      NAME       CITY    COMMISSION
5001         JAMES HOOG   NEW YORK  .15
5006        MC LYON        PARIS    .14
5005        PIT ALEX      LONDON    .11
```

In the above three queries, query 1 and 2 gives the expected output, however query 3 is not providing the expected output. All queries have the same join between city from salesman and customer table, but I am not getting it why query 3 gives a different output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Based on comments, the correct form of the third query should just check whether any salesman's city exists in the customer table:

```
SELECT * FROM SALESMAN SLS  
WHERE SLS.CITY IN  (SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM CUSTOMER CUST)
```

This gives the same results as the first two queries.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4191a3fb1bf1b0f3ada9352e4593338e)

**Original Answer**

The reason your third query gives different results is that the subquery **only** returns the salesman id values that exist in `customer` for each of the cities in `salesman`, which in this case are 5001, 5005 and 5006. So you don't get NAIL KNITE in the output as none of the customers in PARIS, LONDON or NEW YORK have had NAIL as a salesman.

Note that it's arguable that Query 3 actually returns the correct result, as your other queries don't consider whether a given salesman has any customers in any given city. So your other two queries should really be:

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
SLS.*
FROM SALESMAN SLS
JOIN CUSTOMER CUST ON SLS.CITY = CUST.CITY AND SLS.SALESMAN_ID = CUST.SALESMAN_ID
ORDER BY SLS.SALESMAN_ID
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * FROM SALESMAN SLS  
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE SLS.CITY = CUSTOMER.CITY AND CUSTOMER.SALESMAN_ID = SLS.SALESMAN_ID)
ORDER BY SALESMAN_ID
```

With these changes, all three queries give the same result:

```
SALESMAN_ID     NAME        CITY        COMMISSION
5001            JAMES HOOG  NEW YORK    .15
5005            PIT ALEX    LONDON      .11
5006            MC LYON     PARIS       .14
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2084a26c590232de4dbd4d5127fd6920)

Comment: Nick, thanks for your reply.. Regarding the modification that you suggested for query 1 and 2, i get that, but I am not trying to achieve that.. In other words, i want all salesman information provided if any of the customer lives in the same city as the salesman..  So, I am expecting the output that query 1 and 2 gives.. For, query 3 I am assuming it typically replicates an inner join with city from customer and salesman. In that case, my assumption is that the query should have picked up the salesman 5002 since we have one customer that lives in Paris.. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: @siva OK, that makes it more clear. In that case, your third query cannot work, for the reason that it makes an effective join on salesman_id and city, rather than just city. See my edit for a query that will do what you explained in your comment

Comment: Nick, thanks for the suggestion.. Don't know why I didn't think of that :) BTW, the original third query has the join only for city right? Does the subquery imply that the join happens with salesman_id as well? The main reason I am asking about the third query is I am interested to know what is actually happening with the query..

Comment: The original third query effectively joins with salesman_id as well because you use `salesman_id in (select salesman_id ...)` - that's why my new query just uses `city in (select city ...)`

Answer (score 0):

In third query you are missing `join` and you are expecting to work same as your second query. Here is your third query with `join`.

```
SELECT * FROM SALESMAN SLS  
WHERE SLS.SALESMAN_ID 
IN  (
      SELECT 
        DISTINCT CUST.SALESMAN_ID 
      FROM CUSTOMER CUST 
      JOIN SALESMAN_ID SLS
      ON SLS.CITY = CUST.CITY
    )
```

`EXISTS` is much faster than IN when the sub-query results is very large and `IN`  is much faster than `EXISTS` when the sub-query results is very small.